# price calculations weighted values

Tags: excel, vba

After a bit of advice on doing a calculator with a sliding scale.

I am building a matrix where we have set price points at intervals based on qty of items. The code I use works fine apart from the first 2 ranges.

Because for 1 qty the unit cost is so high my maths won't work.

Example
Qty 1 = £23.25 (Price per unit is then £23.25)
Qty 10 = £51.59 (Price per unit is then £5.159)

I then have further quantity's that work out correctly.

What I need to be able to do is some sort of weighted value, for 2 off the unit price needs to be near the £20 a unit mark, then 3 off less etc until I get to 10 off @ £5.159 a unit.

(It costs more for lesser quantity's, we want to encourage more qty)

Has anyone implemented something like this? From 10 qty onwards the calculation is fine as the unit cost changes are not much at all.

Thanks

Comment: That is all rather baffling I'm afraid. Please read [ask].

Comment: There are many ways to do this depending on how your numbers fit a particular modeling technique.  Is it straight line, exponential, power?  The idea is that you must find the trend line formula that best fits your scale then use that formula as a function to get the correct price.  Without seeing your break down of how much per unit per quantity it is hard to help you get to the point you want.

Comment: You could have a lookup table to pick up a specific price related to a range of quantity.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have quantities form 1 to 10, in column `A`, put `23.25` in `B1` and `51.59` in `B10`, then the following formula in `B2`:

```
=B1+(B$10-B$1)/9
```

And populate down to `B9`

in `C1` use the following formula:

```
=B1/A1
```

and populate down. Final result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: yeah this is the normal method I would use. But I have to do it differently, example - for Qty of 2 I need a price of around £40 - (Has to be a lot more for 2 than 9 for example) - so the scale above won't work. I need to somehow get the scale to apply more value based on the lower qty up to my next price point

Comment: See Scott Craner's comment on the desired function. *you* have to decide what it is, then implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use vlookup with a table as so:
[image]